# What is the song used in this Star Trek: TNG special feature?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, music-identification

On the sixth and last disc of the season one blu-ray remastered version of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, there's a bunch of bonus material including a clip called "The Beginning" which uses one particular song as the background music over and over. The song is incredibly familiar, I think it may be a theme song from a movie that may not even be a *Star Trek* movie, but I'm struggling to identify it. What is this song from?

Comment: for those sad souls that don't have the season one blu ray - is there an online video that could be heard?

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried to find the clip online, but did not.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure now that the song is part of the theme from *Star Trek: First Contact*.